# Corda State persist where exactly in DB (IOU Example)

Tags: corda

Corda saves data into Vault. Vault is nothing but Database. By default it has support for H2 database. Corda stores states into H2 table as BLOB. I have performed scan on tables NODE_TRANSACTION, VAULT_LINEAR_STATES and VAULT_STATES. I run IOU Example and performed several transactions. I truncated NODE_TRANSACTION and VAULT_LINEAR_STATES and test on UI but UI was still showing State's data. Data is showing from VAULT_STATES but how it showing is still question. There was no BLOB found in VAULT_STATES my question is where exactly it is referring state in db

Comment: You sure the data that you see not came from cache because if you remove node_transaction you can not query the data anymore.

Comment: Which version you use? in version 3 blob data was keep in node_transaction

Comment: @ Akkapong Kajornwongwattana I am using version 3.1. I used example IOU_EXAMPLE where I truncate entire node_transaction table and referesh UI, UI was still showing data. As you said It may come from cache, how can I check is it coming from cache or NODE_TRANSACTION...Thnx for ur time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table maps each transaction ID to a blob of the transaction. This blob includes the transaction's output states, as well as the other components of the transaction
- The `VAULT_STATES` table references each state by the ID of transaction that created it, and its index in the outputs of that transaction. This (ID, output idx) pair is then used to retrieve the state object from the corresponding blob in the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table